# JavaScript issue on checking if both numeric values exists

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hopefully I get this format right.  I know this is a newbie question and probably pretty obvious but I am confused on how to check these fields.  I have two input fields on a JSP file:

```
 <input id="CMDScheduleNumber" type="number" class="textsmall" maxlength="5"
       onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/>

 <input id="CMDContractYear" type="number" class="textsmall" maxlength="4"
      onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/>
```

I have a function in a script called "searchEFT" that is checking if either the schedule number or contract year is populated then both must be populated.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
          //function for onchange    
          $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#searchEFT").click(function () {

                  var Cmd_Sched_Number = document.getElementById("CMDScheduleNumber");
                  var Cmd_Contract_Year = document.getElementById("CMDContractYear");
                  var Cmd_Status = document.getElementById("CMDSchedStatus");
                  var Cmd_Creation_Date = ocument.getElementById("CMDCreationDate");

                  if (Cmd_Sched_Number == "") {
                      If(Cmd_Contract_Year !== "")
                      alert("Schedule Number and EFT Contract Year must be both populated");
                      return;
                  }
                  else if (Cmd_Sched_Number == "") {
                      alert("Schedule Number and EFT Contract year must be both populated");
                      return;
                  }
```

When I tried to do a debugger if the Cmd_Sched_Number field the value is shown as "" but the valueasnumber is shown as 'NaN'.  So when I do a check, should I check it was "" or check it as numeric with isNaN and/or IsNull?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I recommend looking into jQuery or similar package at some point.  It makes things so much easier.

Comment: The OP is already using something like that. You can see it in the code. That said, it's hardly necessary here.

Comment: For <input> elements, the value property returns a string. The valueAsNumber property attempts to convert the string to a number. If a conversion is not possible then valueAsNumber returns a NaN. Since you are checking whether something was entered, checking value property is ok.

Answer (score 0):

`var Cmd_Sched_Number = document.getElementById("CMDScheduleNumber")`;
Gets the Element.

Use `.value` to get [value](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) from the Element

Something like:

```
var Cmd_Sched_Number = document.getElementById("CMDScheduleNumber").value;
```

Also, since you have jQuery already, consider using it.
Like:

```
var Cmd_Sched_Number = $("CMDScheduleNumber").val();
```

Comment: if(Cmd_Sched_Number.value) would evaluate false on a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Custom code validations are really a mess. How many conditions you can check? There are a lot of open source libraries and they do the job pretty much well.

I would recommend you to use [validate.js](http://validatejs.org/). Its very simple and easy to use. It sets the rules on the fields and validate according to them.

Probably you will have to do little more efforts right now to shift your code, but it will be very easy then.

Comment: Custom code validations are a mess only if you're messing them ; ).

Comment: If you have a good source available I think you should use it.

Comment: Considering the question, there's no library which could work for OP, if they don't know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

As Aragorn correctly pointed out, make sure you're getting the values, not the Jquery objects or DOM elements.

```
function isPopulated(val) {
   return !(val === '' || isNaN(val));
}

//and then in your click event handler...:

if((isPopulated(Cmd_Sched_Number) || isPopulated(Cmd_Contract_Year)) && !(isPopulated(Cmd_Sched_Number) && isPopulated(Cmd_Contract_Year))) {
  //Handle the case where one is populated and the other isn't, assuming you want to treat any non-numbers as not populated.
}
```

This is if you want a common block for any scenario of one populated and the other not, it will be evaluated like an XOR.

The reason my isPopulated function checks for both an empty string and isNaN is that isNaN('') will evaluated false.

If you don't care whether the entered value is actually numeric or not, then you would maybe want to check value.length > 0, for example.